# Can SQL Server CE support multiple connection from different pc at a time?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-ce

I have an windows desktop application running with with SQL Server CE, now my customer request to have a network version for this application, my question is can SQL Server CE support multiple connection and transaction at a time? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It does support multiple connections **from the same computer** according to this technet document:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb380177%28SQL.90%29.aspx

The relevant section of the document:

> SSCE Concurrency
>
> SSCE allows multiple connections to the same database (.sdf file) from the same application or even multiple applications on the same computer. This gives you more freedom to structure your application as needed, such as allowing the user to continue to interact with data while performing synchronization with a back-end database, or to have multiple applications on the same machine share an SSCE data store. Transactional concurrency locks are made by the database engine to prevent concurrent connections from accessing the same records at the same time. The technical limit on concurrent connections for a single database is 256, but 70-80 is a better practical limit from a performance perspective.

Comment: Do multiple users (loading the same Intranet app on a server) each count toward the 256 connections limit?

Answer (score 0):

No, for this requirement, you can use the free SQL Server Express